# Why so much noise in my scipy.FFT and does it need normalising?

Tags: python

I have experience of doing ffts in matlab but am new to python, I am trying to generate a signal and perform an fft using `scipy`/`numpy`/`matplotlib`. The output graph seems noisy and the amplitude seems high, what am I doing wrong? 
Any help would be appreciated...

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import fft

fs = 44100.0
f = 10000.0
f2 = 6000.0;
ts = 1.0/fs
dur = 1
x = np.arange(0, dur, ts);
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*f*x) + 0.5*np.sin(2*np.pi*f2*x);
y = y/np.max(np.abs(y));

N = len(y);
Y = fft(y, N)
Y = Y[0:round(N/2)]
magsY = abs(Y);
magsY = 20*np.log10(magsY);

f = np.linspace(0, fs/2, round(N/2))
plt.figure()
plt.plot(y)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(f, magsY)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's noisy at all. It looks that way because of you take the log of `magsY`. Instead, it may be easier to see if you comment out `magsY = 20*np.log10(magsY)` and use a `semilogy` plot on `magsY` instead. You would just change the `plt.plot(f, magsY)` to `plt.semilogy(f, magsY)`.

[image: semilogy plot]

Your noise peaks around a level of `10e-8` and your actual signal is sitting at `~10e4`. Your signal-to-noise ratio is then `10e4/10e-8 = 10e12`. To me, this isn't noisy but if this is too much for you, then take a closer look at your actual signal (`y`). If you zoom in you'll see that the points are very jagged. You'll need to increase your resolution to produce a nicer looking signal.

[image: jagged edges]

Edit:
To add a little bit more--The absolute amplitude of the peaks is not really what's important. Instead, their amplitudes relative to each other is what is really useful. For your data set, I extracted that the `f=10000` peak has an amplitude of `15550.74669` and the `f=6000` peak has an amplitude of `7775.37335`. The ratio of these is `1.9999999987`which is exactly what we should expect from how you constructed `y`; the frequency `f` is twice as prevalent as frequency `f2`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed response, i guess this was more DSP related rather than code. I've been working on filter design too much and expected to see a nice smooth plot, like that from a unit impulse. Facinated by how much there is to explore in Python, there's a tonne of libraries to it :)